# How to initialize the zoom at a given scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code below which is a `d3.js` force directed graph:

```js
var graph = {  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8},
    {"id": "BaronessT", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Enjolras", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Combeferre", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Feuilly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bahorel", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bossuet", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Joly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Grantaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9},
    {"id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Babet", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Claquesous", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Toussaint", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Child1", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Child2", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Brujon", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 , "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1, "type":"A"}
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
  
  var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
 .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

 zoom_handler(svg);   

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(300).id(function(d) {
            return d.id;
        }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
  
  var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "everything");


  var link = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")

 
   var circles = node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

 var lables = node.append("text") // Labeling for nodes
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      })
      .attr('x', 6)
      .attr('y', 3);

  node.append("title") 
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
 
  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  node 
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
  
};

      function zoom_actions(){
 g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
 }
  
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</style>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


</html>
</div>

<svg width="798" height="400"></svg>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, on the initial load, the zoom level is way too close and doesn't look nice.

Is there any way of setting the initial zoom level further so that I wont have to zoom out myself.

I have tried to use the following code but it doesn't seem to work well for my current situation. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zooming);

vis = svg.append("svg:svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .call(zoom) // here
     .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(100, 50).scale(0.5))
     .append("svg:g")
     .attr("transform","translate(100,50) scale(.5,.5)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were in the right direction. Here is a modified version of your code which initializes the zoom in order to have the whole layout within the parent container:

```js
var graph = {  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8},
    {"id": "BaronessT", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Enjolras", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Combeferre", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Feuilly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bahorel", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bossuet", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Joly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Grantaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9},
    {"id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Babet", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Claquesous", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Toussaint", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Child1", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Child2", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Brujon", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 , "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1, "type":"A"},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1, "type":"A"}
  ]
};
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var zoom_handler = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom_actions);

// zoom_handler(svg);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(300).id(function(d) {
  return d.id;
}))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "everything");

svg.call(zoom_handler)
  .call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(200, 150).scale(0.2));

var link = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "links")
.selectAll("line")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

var node = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("g")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g")


var circles = node.append("circle")
.attr("r", 8)
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
.call(d3.drag()
.on("start", dragstarted)
.on("drag", dragged)
.on("end", dragended));

var lables = node.append("text") // Labeling for nodes
.text(function(d) {
  return d.id;
})
.attr('x', 6)
.attr('y', 3);

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.id; });

simulation
.nodes(graph.nodes)
.on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
.links(graph.links);

function ticked() {
  link
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  node
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })

};

function zoom_actions(){
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```css
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


</html>
</div>

<svg width="798" height="400"></svg>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The only change consists in setting the initial state of the zoom by calling the `transform` operation with a `scale` transformation (the `translate` step is there to center back the layout):

```
svg.call(zoom_handler)
  .call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(200, 150).scale(0.2));
```

Here, I've zoomed out by 5 (`scale(1/5)`).

[Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform) is the complete `d3-zoom` api and [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#transform_scale) is the `zoom.scale` documentation.